# How to list enumerated USB devices and their status in Linux (Ubuntu) and MAC

Tags: linux, macos, ubuntu, mac, usb

I am using devcon to check enumerated USB devices and their status on windows, I get the following output when running for example "devcon status usb*":

```
USB\VID_0557&PID_2213&MI_00\7&2A125440&0&0000
    Name: USB Input Device
    Driver is running.
USB\VID_0557&PID_2213&MI_01\7&2A125440&0&0001
    Name: USB Input Device
    Driver is running.

2 matching device(s) found.
```

I am looking for a way to do this on Linux (Ubuntu) and MAC, and be able to see if device is enabled, disabled, has a problem etc, all this I can do with devcon for windows.

I know there's lsusb for linux but I couldn't see how I can get the status from the list (I tried -v -t etc).
For mac I understand there's system_profiler, will this show me the status also?

Thanks,
Michal

Comment: What do you mean under "status"? Maybe you just need udev?

Comment: I guess I mean the driver status.. if it is enabled or disabled, if it was installed/identified successfully. In windows you can enable and disable the driver, and if a driver is missing or has some error and you see the USB device with a yellow bang in the device manager - it is all exposed using devcon. I don't know if there's an equivalent for this in Linux and Mac.

Comment: In linux there's no "driver": if your hardware uses kernel module, you can do `modprobe` or `rmmod`. If it's on libusb, you can't "disable driver".

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that then.. What about Mac?